# How to redeploy a react application hosted on digital ocean droplet

Tags: node.js, reactjs, digital-ocean, droplet

I deployed a react app using digital ocean droplet.

I have made changes to the application, please how can I redeploy the application so the changes can appear.?

The application is live already, I want to make changes to the production code.

I hosted the code on github and cloned it into node js in the droplet.

Please, is my first time of deploying with digital ocean.

I will appreciate all the assistance.

Comment: follow the same steps, you used to deploy the first time.

Comment: You mean, like installing nodejs, pm2 and nginx again? Also i should reclone the github?

Comment: pull the new changes in your droplet and build

Comment: Okay, but please i can't really understand what you mean by pull the new changes. Please can you explain better? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean like do git add. and git push remote and then do npm run build in droplet? Can i do that inside the droplet?

Comment: use ```git pull``` to pull the new changes

Comment: Okay, you mean like, i should commit the changes i have made on the github, then i should go to the droplet and pull it then i should run npm build again?

Comment: correct. commit your changes and pull them from the droplet

Comment: okay, Thanks so much. I will do it now and let you know.